# Is there a problem from the conditional expression

Tags: kotlin

> Write a program that reads a word and prints all the letters that aren't present in this word.  Only lowercase letters are counted.

I thought it would remove hello from a..z, instead it's printing true

```
val input = Scanner(System.`in`)
val inp = input.nextLine() //hello
val alp = mutableListOf('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')

for (i in inp) {
    if (i in alp) {
        val a = alp.remove(i)
        print(a)
    }
}
```

Comment: The `break` keyword will finish your loop at the first step because `h` is in the collection. Remove the `break`

Comment: Ok thanks, but it's only printing "true" instead of the remaining alphabets without hello

Comment: That's because you are printing `a` which is the result of `remove` method (and it succeeded) not the `alp` collection. I don't want to be mean but I'm not sure did you spent even one day working on it...

Comment: I actually did i'm just learning programming smiles, please help me with the code how to get the final output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MutableList.remove()` returns a Boolean indicating whether there were any instances to remove. And you're printing the value every time. Since you're iterating the input word, you would only be able to print letters that were in the word from within the loop. To fix your code, you would need to modify it like this:

```
for (i in inp) {
    alp.remove(i)
}
println(alp.joinToString(""))
```

But it would be easier to use the `filterNot` function on an alphabet Char range.

```
val alp = ('a'..'z').filterNot { it in inp }
println(alp.joinToString(""))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val notInWord = CharRange('a','z').run { 
     minus(input.asSequence())
 }.also { 
     it.forEach { ch ->print(ch) }
 }
```

Here are some notes:

1. Creating a `CharRanage` for all  lowercase letters (equivalent to `('a'..'z')`)
2. Using `Minus` with user's input as `Sequence<Char>` in order to eturn a list
   containing all elements of the original collection except the elements
   contained in the given sequence.
3. Iterate over the `List` and print the elements using `also` as final block